# Define and calculate the transpose transformation $T^t(f)$ on dual space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $V=P_1(\mathbb{R})$ and $W=\mathbb{R}^2$ with the corresponding basis $b= \left \{ 1,x \right \}$ and $g= \left \{ e_1,e_2 \right \}$ We define the linear transformation $T:V\rightarrow W$ $$T(p)=(p(0)-2p(1),p(0)+{p}'(0))$$

if $f \in  W^{\ast } $ with: $$f(a,b)=a-2b$$

Calculate $T^t(f)$.

My first idea was to find the basis matrix of the transformation $T(f)$ and then find the transpose matrix, but I can't figure out how to define  $T(f)$ it seems like $f \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ but $T$ takes elements of $\mathbb{R}$ that really confuse me.
I calculated $[T]^{g}_{b}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &-2 \\ 
 1& 1
\end{pmatrix}$ and therefore $[T^t]^{b^{\ast }}_{g^{\ast }}=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 &1 \\ 
 -2& 1
\end{pmatrix}$ but i am unable to fully understand what  $T^t(f)$ means.

Comment: Your solution is right. You could check up what's the precise definition of a transpose of a linear transformation is. It is a map from the dual space of $W$, $W^*$ to the dual space of $V$, $V^*$ defined for each $f$ by $T^t(f)=f.T$ ($.$ is composition operation). Using two bases of $V$ and $W$ and their dual basis you could prove the formula you used relating the matrix representation of $T$ with the matrix representation of its transpose.

Comment: How can I calculate $[T^t]^{b^{\ast }}_{g^{\ast }}$ directly from $T^t(f)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it if $T^t(f)=f(T)$ then $f(T)=p(0)-2p(1)-2(p(0)+{p(0)}')$ plugging in the $b$ basis we get $-3,-4$ so  $T^t(f)=-3a-4b$

Is this correct?